# Unity3D idle player animation overrides jump animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've followed the brackeys tutorials to make a 2D Player Character jump but having issues with the jump animation. When I hit jump, the Player goes into the air but it'll play the idle animation in the air til I give another keyboard input. If I hit jump again while in the air, it'll play the jump animation and go back to idle when hitting the ground.

In the animator I noticed that the jump animation triggers fast and seems to be overridden by the idle animation. I've loaded and compared the working final brackeys project, and rebuilt the animator nodes. The code and everything in the editor are the same but the only thing I can think of is that I'm using different art assets.

Here are the tutorials I followed.

2D Movement: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA

2D Animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8

Comment: Please include more details, code, animation nodes etc so we can help you diagnose the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post some screenshots of your Animator Controller, its animation settings or code, please? I suspect it might have something to do with transitions or events.